# Получение текста, обрамленного кавычками, из строк

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно вытащить текст, обрамленный кавычками, из строк `graph_id1[id2]`. `id1` и `id2` буду подставлять для выбора конкретной строки

```
graph_1188589077[1188591077] = "Количество помещений (зданий) - всего, единиц     (1)";
graph_1188589077[1188592077] = "из них число памятников истории и культуры федерального значения (2)";
graph_1188589077[1188593077] = "из них число памятников истории и культуры регионального значения (3)";
```

Comment: Что Вы сделали сами? Что не получилось?

Comment: @ReinRaus
Pattern.compile("^.*graph_1188589077.1188591077. = [\"]([^\"]*)\"");
Работает на отдельной строке, но теперь другая проблема :
Забираю весь код страницы с помощью jsoup и переводя в стриг (видимо) regexp читает первую строку, на которой конечно не то что ищу, как сделать так что бы паттерн искал по всему стрингу?

Comment: @ReinRaus все получилось, добавил в паттер поиск по всем строкам 
        Pattern.compile("^.*graph_1188589077.1188591077. = [\"]([^\"]*)\"",Pattern.MULTILINE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отправляю закрыть как дубликат, потому что смысл немного разный, но суть одна.
И решение одинаково.
Изначально ничего не находилось из-за привязки регулярного выражения к началу текста `^`. Не нужно было это делать, если не важно что находится вне кавычек.

Регулярное выражение будет очень простым:

```
"(.*?)"
```

Или в виде кода:

```
Pattern.compile( "\"(.*?)\"" );
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает